# How to add an attribute to the form tag itself and not just a field in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, spam

I am having trouble stopping bots filling in spam while letting through legit users. I have a honeypot field with `autocomplete="off"` attribute but it doesn't seem to be working. From what i've read, the best cross browser solution is to add `autocomplete="false"` to the main form tag itself, e.g. `<form autocomplete="false">...</form>`. What is the best way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do that in your template where the form is added.

In a template you'd typically do something like;

```
    <form autocomplete="false">
        {% csrf_token %}
   
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.label }}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
        {% endfor %}
```

So just add whatever you want to the form tag.

You should probably also have a look at including recaptcha if you've got spam problems.

And remember that v3 doesn't require any selecting street lights etc

https://pypi.org/project/django-recaptcha/

Comment: @DermotMcGrath That solves it for you then? Want to mark this as the right answer?